# Calendar Kal : how to refresh the tableview dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, calendar, kal

Hi everyone i am developping a tab bar application where one of the tabs is the Calendar from Kal library (http://github.com/klazuka/Kal).

I use CoreData as the DataSource for the Kal. It works perfectly but the table view below the Cal is never "refreshing".

I mean, the table view is initialized with the events between the first day in month, and the last day in month.

But, i want the table view the list of events "dynamically" changed.

Example:

I have created two events : one at january 4th, one at january 8th.

The tableview is always showing the two events and no take care of the day selected in month.
I mean, even if the day selected is January, 22nd, the two events are still displayed.

How can i load the calendar with all the events of the month and the tableview only with the events of the day ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To reload the data that's been inserted:

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Yes, i know this is the method to reload the data in a table view.

But, what I need is to refresh with a specifical date in order to avoid have all the events displayed whatever the date selected is. 

So, when i tapped on January 4th, i only have (if they exist), the events of January, 4th, for instance.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well then try saving the events of each day into their own `NSDictionary`, and then display the correct `NSDictionary` for it's respective day when selected.

Comment: It's okay, i have managed to found the error. For those in the same case, just follow the code in HolidaySqliteDataSource.m in the Kal source in github. My mistake. Thanks anyway.